# Multiple taxonomy views do not work

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I got taxonomy menu 'Categories' which list all Terms as menu links, so when clicked, it would open a list of items tagged with that term:
[image]

So if you click on Hats & Visors, it would open the list of hats and visors. The problem is, that it doesn't, only the first view (in this case t-shirts) works. In the rest of the views it only generates empty views container. Also if I changed filter in the T-Shirts view to filter Hats & Visors, it would work, the Hats & Visors section would show hats, but then T-Shirts section would stop working. I do not understand the problem.

My views settings:
[image]

Non-working views:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Boy this is a big one. Got solution with Commerce Search API, simply re-created Kickstart's Collection view and got same result. View looks like this now:
[image]

As you can see it all runs in one Display only. Each taxonomy term menu link generates a view display for its category term listing product display nodes rendered via entities.

Also following this Commerce Search API video tutorial really helped to understand the basics how it works: http://vimeo.com/53404289